# How to check rails application properly connected to MSSQL database or not

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

How to check rails application properly connected to MSSQL database or not(in controller/model)

Can anybody assist me on this?

Answer (score 0):

`ActiveRecord::Base.connected?` can be used to check your connection. 
You can find [here](https://gist.github.com/limhoff-r7/71ee6b1568b604e131a8)  a gist that does a little bit more complex check.

Answer (score 0):

`ActiveRecord::Base.connection_config` will give your connection details and `ActiveRecord::Base.connected?` will return a true or false value.
 Refer [here](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/connection/class)